# How do I filter lists of objects in django template?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I want to create a filter box where I can filter lists of objects:

```
**models.py**

class Personal(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    email = models.EmailField()
    age = models.DateField(null=True)
    non_veg = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    alcohol = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    pure_veg = models.BooleanField(default=False)

**forms.py**

class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Personal
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'age', 'non-veg', 'alcohol', 'pure_veg']

**views.py**

def my_personal(request):
    my_data = Personal.objects.all()
    return render(request, "personal.html", data)

**personal.html**

<body>
<div id="filter_list">
    <h3>Filter By</h3>
    <h4>Age</h4>
    <select>
        <option value="1"> From 18 to 20 years</option>
        <option value="2"> From 21 to 25 years</option>
        <option value="3"> From 26 to 30 years</option>
        <option value="4"> From 31 to 35 years</option>
        <option value="5"> From 36 to 40 years</option>
        <option value="6"> Above 40 years</option>
    </select>
    <h4>Likes</h4>
        <input type="checkbox" name="non_veg"> Non-Veg Food
        <input type="checkbox" name="alcohol"> Alcohol
        <input type="checkbox" name="pet_allowed"> Pure Veg
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Apply filters">
</body>
```

with the above example if I select the age 18 to 20 years and tick non-veg Food checkbox and click on apply filter, it should show the persons who likes non-veg with age limit 18 to 20 years on the **SAME PAGE**.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to obviously wrap your fields in a `<form method="GET" action="."></form>`
2. You have to name your fields. your drop down does not have a name.
3. You have to give same name for checkbox.
4. After submitting your form, in your views request.GET will have the submitted data. Filter your queryset based on request.GET.

Your are passing context wrong. You must have an error here return render(request, "personal.html", data), because there is no such thing data.